# Web development which is best Angular Js or Wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, html

I am developing 1 project but I am little bit confused to choose which technology I should use

1. I go for AngularJs, but why AngularJs?
2. I go for WordPress, but why WordPress?

Can anyone suggest me the best option?

Comment: There is a difference in these two technologies since wordpress is a content management system while angularjs is a javascript framework for creating single page applications. You should make a choice based on the requirements of your project.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is not so simple, because there are many types of fields on which selected technologies can be used and as @steur36 said before, it depends on your project requirements.

Basically, **Wordpress** is a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) and its prime functionality is to provide all functionality to run and display a simple webpage (its a mix of frontend and backend). Wordpress could be used with success for small websites or blogs (where the main feature is to provide and/or display basic content, like: text, images/media/gallery, files ect.)

In the other side, there is the **AngularJS**, a javascript [frontend framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_web_development) where you can focus on visual side of your project and how the content is present to the audience. With AngularJS (or any other javascript frontend framework, like: Ember, Backbone, ect.) you can build the appearance of any webpage or web application, but to store the content, you may also need some [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) backend server as well (to create queries to the server).

**As small summary**, Wordpress is great for small and medium websites/blogs (for bigger projects, it might not be adequate). With AngularJS (and probably with some RESTful backend server, because it depends if you really need it) you may create almost any complex projects, but the time of creation will definitely increase relative to Wordpress.